# Why SQLBulkTool Insert Failed with Connection Error?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulktools

I am testing the SQLBulkTool version 2.1.13 with basic DB options on my laptop

**TESTING ENVIRONMENT**
SQL Server 2019
OS: Windows 11
Visual Studion 2022

**1) In SQL, I created a small table: SimpleBook with three columns:**

```
  Id Int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  ISBN varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  Description varchar(50) NULL
```

**2) Write a test program:  SQLBulkToolTest &  Create a object class**

```
namespace SQLBulkToolTest.DataObjs
{
    public class SimpleBook
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public SimpleBook() { }
        public SimpleBook(string iSBN, string description)
        {
            ISBN = iSBN;
            Description = description;
        }

    }
}
```

**3) The Code Segment to Test bulk insert**

```
public BulkOperations bulk = new BulkOperations();
public DataTableOperations dtOps = new DataTableOperations();
        
public List<SimpleBook> GetBooks()
{
    List<SimpleBook> bookList = new();
    bookList.Add(new SimpleBook("ISBN001", "Next Gen Computing"));
    bookList.Add(new SimpleBook("ISBN002", "Program development patterns"));
    bookList.Add(new SimpleBook("ISBN003", "Learn c#"));

    return bookList;
}

public bool InsertData()
{
    bool isOk = false;

    try
    {
        List<SimpleBook> bookList = GetBooks();

        using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dapperConnStr))
            {
                bulk.Setup<SimpleBook>()
                    .ForCollection(bookList)
                    .WithTable("SimpleBook")
                    .AddAllColumns()
                    .BulkInsert()
                    .SetIdentityColumn(x => x.Id)
                    .Commit(conn);
            }
            trans.Complete();
        }

        isOk = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    return isOk;
}
```

**4) Testing Steps and Errors**

The DB connection string has been successfully tested before running "InsertData" method

When executing "InsertData" method, the exception was triggered with following error:

> Error message: Parameter must be a SqlConnection instance

> Stack Trace:
> at SqlBulkTools.BulkInsert`1.Commit(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction)
> at SQLBulkToolTest.DbBulkOps.InsertData() in C:\Projects\my_tryout\SQLBulkToolTest\SQLBulkToolTest\DbBulkOps.cs:line 71

**I have not been able to figure out what caused the error in my testing code. Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at the `bulk.Setup...` command and inspected the `conn` variable? Is the SqlConnection valid and connected?

Comment: Not a Dapper user here, but does it need the connection to be open?

Comment: @tim-jarosz:  I added the conn.open() statement after "using (SqlConnection  conn ....)". After setting up the break point, I was able to see the connection state is "open".  Unfortunately, I still got the same error.